# Visual Studio 9.0 Beta Program files in C:\

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've several Visual Studio 9.0 Beta Program files in C:\ root directory:

```
eula.1028.txt
eula.1031.txt
eula.1033.txt
eula.1036.txt
eula.1040.txt
eula.1041.txt
eula.1042.txt
eula.2052.txt
eula.3082.txt
globdata.ini
install.exe
install.ini
install.res.1028.dll
install.res.1031.dll
install.res.1033.dll
install.res.1036.dll
install.res.1040.dll
install.res.1041.dll
install.res.1042.dll
install.res.2052.dll
install.res.3082.dll
vcredist.bmp
VC_RED.MSI
VC_RED.cab
```

I've VS 2008 Professional and 2010 Professional installed. Do I need the files mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you should be safe deleting those files. (If you're worried about it, just move them to the Recycle Bin or another folder; then leave 'em there for a few days to see if anything goes wrong.)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need those files, you can safely delete them. These files are created due to a bug in the Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (Visual Studion 2008 = Visual Studio 9). There is a KB article on that: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950683

Answer (score 1):

These files are unnecessary and can be safely deleted from the system. The functioning of the runtime library will not be affected by this.
Its a known bug and is fixed in VS2008 SP1.