# Can I safely delete files created by Visual Studio from external drive?

Tags: visual-studio

When I installed Visual Studio, it also placed hundreds of files on my external hard drive. And now the folder structure is full of "junk" that I don't want.

[image]

Is it safe to delete these files? Will deleting these files affect my Visual Studio installation (which is on a different disk) at all? Why does VS do this anyway? Why does it place all this crap on a drive I never even gave it permission to put it on in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely delete any of those files, since, quoting Microsoft KB,

> These temporary files are erroneously generated by the installer into the root directory of one of your drives, instead of the temp directory

Those are temporary files indeed and they, still quoting Microsoft,

> are generated on the root directory of a drive that has the largest available space in the system

Check Microsoft knowledgebase pages like [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/950683) for more detail.

Comment: Thank you @ibanjo. I always have troubles trying to find what I need in the KB pages.

Answer (score 1):

What about archiving those files, opening visual studio and check it is still working?
If it doesn't just put the files back where they were...

Comment: The problem with this solution is that even though I have USB 3.0 (which I believe to be nothing more than a gimmick), transferring many GB's of these files from the external drive to somewhere else is just too time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

You should be safe deleting those files. Someone already asked this question. :D

[Visual Studio 9.0 Beta Program files in C:\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355065/visual-studio-9-0-beta-program-files-in-c)

hope I was helpfull 
Jasper.

Answer (score 1):

**Cause**

These temporary files are erroneously generated by the installer into the root directory of one of your drives, instead of the temp directory.

**Resolution**

These files are unnecessary and can be safely deleted from the system. The functioning of the runtime library will not be affected by this.
Its a known bug and is fixed in VS2008 SP1.

Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/950683

Comment: Just curious... If it was fixed in VS2008 SP1... Why am I only having this problem with VS2015? Weird.